# MYSQL USING SUB SELECT TO WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

HI I would like to ask if possible to call my sub select in where clause like example the `HELPER1` would be use as `WHERE HELPER1 LIKE 'SAMPLE%'`

Here's my sample query

```
SELECT dispatch_id, FROM_UNIXTIME(expected_departure_date, '%Y-%m%-%d %h:%i:%s') as dt,
FROM_UNIXTIME(expected_wh_arrival, '%Y-%m%-%d %h:%i:%s') as at, truck, FROM_UNIXTIME(created_on, '%Y-%m%-%d %h:%i:%s') as created,remarks, agent_id,
(SELECT fullname FROM dev.tpl_user_profiles WHERE uid=helper1_id) as hp1,
(SELECT fullname FROM dev.tpl_user_profiles WHERE uid=helper2_id) as hp2,
(SELECT fullname FROM dev.tpl_user_profiles WHERE uid=helper3_id) as hp3,
(SELECT fullname FROM dev.tpl_user_profiles WHERE uid=helper4_id) as hp4,
(SELECT fullname FROM dev.tpl_user_profiles WHERE uid=helper5_id) as hp5,
(SELECT fullname FROM dev.tpl_user_profiles WHERE uid=driver) as driver1,
(SELECT fullname FROM dev.tpl_user_profiles WHERE uid=driver2) as driver2,
(SELECT fullname FROM dev.tpl_user_profiles WHERE uid=dispatcher_uid) as dispatcher,
(SELECT td.destination FROM dev.tpl_destination as td WHERE td.id=tdd.destination ) as dest,
(SELECT delivery_type FROM dev.tpl_delivery_type WHERE id=delivery_type ) as det,
 (SELECT plate_number FROM dev.tpl_trucks  WHERE id=truck ) as pn ,
 status
from dev.tpl_dispatch as tdd WHERE
EXISTS (SELECT td.destination FROM dev.tpl_destination as td WHERE td.destination LIKE 'Ac%')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  SQL does not allow the use of a column alias in the `WHERE` for the `SELECT` where it is defined.

I can think of three options:

1. Use a subquery.  But this imposes overhead for materializing the subquery (in MySQL, not other databases).
2. Rearrange the query to use `LEFT JOIN` rather than subqueries.  But that is a lot of work.
3. Use the MySQL extension to `HAVING`.

In a non-aggregation query, MySQL allows you to use a `HAVING` clause that refers to the column aliases.  So you can add:

```
HAVING HELPER1 LIKE 'SAMPLE%'
```

Comment: i tried left join but it took to much time while executing with 100k records which do you think the fastest way to use regards

Comment: i also tried your code by adding HAVING but it did not give me any result

Comment: @DrianDrian . . . Perhaps no rows match the condition.

Comment: hmm there's a record i just copy paste the value from other table but the result is empty or no rows found